# Variance of the probabilty $P(X<x)$

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a problem which involves U-statistics and I reached the expression $\operatorname{Var}(F(X))$, where $F(x)=P(X<x)$, and X is a continuous random variable. Could I simply the expression using some properties or I have to give the answer as a function of $F(x)$?.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is better way to start, but notice that: $\mathbb{P}(F(X) \le x) = \mathbb{P}(X \le F^{-1}(x)) = F(F^{-1}(x))$.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Anyhow, it is well known that $F(X)$ has uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ in this situation and on base of that you can directly find $\mathsf{Var}(F(X))$.

Comment: @openspace Even if $F$ does not have an inverse, $P((F(X) \leq x)=x$ for $x\in [0,1]$ as long as $F$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that F(X) has uniform [0,1] distribution. The answer is Var(F(X))= 1/12 then.

Comment: There's no $U$-statistics in the question. It looks like $X \sim U[0,1]$, so $X$ has uniform distribution. But "to have uniform distribution" is not "to be a $U$-statistic".